# How can I perform the vacuum using the PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to vacuum the PostgreSQL database in production server. I am very new to do this. So anybody knows the PostgreSQL steps, please guide me.

I think it's very useful to improve the performance of PostgreSQL in production server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Connect to the database and issue this command: "VACUUM".  This causes a run in "lazy mode" that can be used during normal production use.  It is recommended you actually invoke it as "vacuum analyze" which will also update statistics.

If you want to see lots of detail, you can at the console type "vacuum verbose"

The more extreme form is "vacuum full" which causes heavy table locking and cannot really be used on a production system.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/maintenance.html

Comment: Please don't link to a manual of an outdated (and non-supported) version. You can replace the version number (8.1) with the text "current" to have a static link to the up-to-date manual

Comment: This usually happens because google winds up giving the url to the older version because it is the most referenced on the web in general. There was some discussion on how to stop this happening on the pgsql-general list but I think it was determined there wasn't much to be done about it.

Comment: `The more extreme form is "vacuum full" which causes heavy table locking and cannot really be used on a production system.`  If this is an older system that does not have auto-vacuum, vacuum full is probably recommended.  Just do it during low traffic.

Answer (score 7):

If you're running a recent version of PostgreSQL you likely have auto-vacuum running so the benefits of running VACUUM manually may be very minimal.

Comment: Thanks for your respose.

Comment: Does auto-vacuum perform vacuum full or just regular vacuum?

Comment: @Hadi - auto-vacuum performs as the regular vacuum and not vacuum full